# How to get driving (paper) maps in the county of Dorset?

Tags: uk, driving, maps

I'm coming from Australia to visit my Dad in Bridport (UK) in Dorset.

We want to drive to Bristol to see the [Brunel Museum](http://www.ssgreatbritain.org/about-us/being-brunel) and we want to direct ourselves to see the [Clifton Suspension Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifton_Suspension_Bridge) on the way.

To plan out our driving journey, we'd like to get a paper map.

My question is: **How to get driving (paper) maps in Dorset?**

Comment: I would bet the people of [Visit Dorset](https://www.visit-dorset.com/) or one of their [visitor information centers](https://www.visit-dorset.com/visitor-information/tourist-information-centre-s) would know.

Comment: Both the sites you mention are in Bristol, which isn't in Dorset.

Comment: If you can get someone to drop you off at a railway station you could get a train to Bristol arriving in Brunel's Temple Meads station and avoid the hassle of parking in Bristol.

Comment: You can buy a road atlas in most stationery/book stores in England.  They're cheap, easy to read, and plan-worthy.

Comment: @mdewey the nearest station is Axminster but Dorchester West has direct trains to Bristol Temple Meads, so that looks good.  But if they do drive, the OP might like to consider [Long Ashton Park and Ride](https://travelwest.info/park-ride/bristol/long-ashton) -- easy enough to get to from the south and well located for the suspension bridge

Comment: A really interesting question is, (these days) **do they still sell paper maps in petrol stations** in the UK?

Comment: @Fattie yes, though the choice in supermarket petrol stations (best value for fuel and account for many of them in towns) is poor. At the motorway services or on a major A road you can expect a good selection.

Comment: Thanks @DaveP - as @ ChrisH has commented - I need a map to get there.

Comment: Thanks @mdewey - that's super helpful. Temple Meads station has been very talked up here in Sydney.

Comment: @ChrisH Oops, my bad. I really should read the question properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Geographers' A-Z Map Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographers%27_A-Z_Map_Company) (who do the famous London A-Z street atlas) also do similar roadmaps for every UK county and city, including Dorset (county) and Bristol (the city of your two stated destinations). You can buy all their products [online](http://www.az.co.uk/?nid=2), and at large stationery shops, for example WH Smith, you will find the relevant *local* maps. The [South West England and South Wales A-Z Road Map](http://www.az.co.uk/?nid=33&iid=13716) covers Bridport and Bristol on one map, although you might prefer to use road signs to get into the coverage of the larger-scale [50 miles around Bristol](http://www.az.co.uk/?nid=33&iid=13806) map.

**That said** I would **heartily** recommend that one of you downloads the Waze app on their smartphone and uses that for navigation. Waze has the google map data and also, crucially for UK driving, has access to crowdsourced live traffic data. You really don't want to find yourself on the M5 on one of its bad days...

Comment: For such a short journey if you don't have data for your phone (or it's expensive) checking the traffic before you set off should be sufficient. Also avoiding the M5 and going via Shepton Mallet works well (or via Glastonbury and/or Wells, to see them on the way)

Comment: Google Maps traffic data is (IME) pretty good - no need for a separate app.

Comment: @ChrisH pretty much all UK airports sell SIM cards for 10-20 pounds. That's comparable to the cost of a map.

Comment: @JonathanReez fair point, it's a while since I looked.  But I tend to aaoid the assumption that visitors (or indeed anyone) will always have a connection.  If you do go across country the signal isn't great in that area (I was cycling there at the weekend) which is another reason to use paper or check before you leave.

Comment: @ChrisH there are also offline maps available with excellent coverage... honestly there's no reason to ever use paper maps anymore for driving.

Comment: @JonathanReez I've tried a few offline mapping solutions (and have google maps cached, as the best free/cheap option for me).  Paper maps are great though -- you can see a huge area at decent resolution in one go, they don't run out of battery, crash, or pop up a notification at an inconvenient moment (I navigate on my phone on the bike, and have had a "sign in to wifi" screen come up just as I get to a junction, from the pub on the corner)

Answer (score 6):

The Ordnance Survey do road maps, and the one you'd need is sheet [7 - South West England](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/shop/maps/roadmap-7-south-west-england.html). Saying that, for actual navigation I'd always recommend a traditional road atlas (combined with, as AakashM says, a traffic-watching GPS to avoid the snarl-ups on the M5). You should be able to get one in any decent bookshop, or in most petrol stations or motorway services. I'd got for one of the "concise" ones that are a smaller size, as the big A3 size ones can be rather unwieldy. Something like [this one](https://www.theworks.co.uk/p/maps-and-atlases/aa-concise-road-atlas-britain---2018/9780749578626) from the AA, for example.

Answer (score 5):

If you're sure you want paper maps, it's probably best to just get a UK road atlas. The UK isn't a very big country so they're not very expensive.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which asks where/how to get them

Comment: @NickC It's a book. Amazon?

Comment: Any petrol station

Comment: @IanTurton - I was going to say that. They sell them at every motorway services and every petrol station.

Answer (score 4):

Paper road atlases designed for exactly this are usually pretty widely and cheaply available in the UK from stationers such as WH Smith or Waterstone's, or any of a number of independent local retailers. You could probably buy one in advance from your favourite online retailer to be delivered to your UK destination, ready for you. A nationwide atlas is likely to be perfectly workable and not that expensive (under GBP 10); I've usually only bothered with county-specific atlases (note, as another poster said, that the sites you're looking for are in Bristol, not Dorset) where I need fine detail of residential areas.

All that said, I wouldn't buy one and haven't in years. Waze is an excellent free GPS navigation application with crowdsourced traffic data and more up-to-date maps which will make your journey much smoother. If you're concerned about data charges, Google Maps is also excellent for satnav and can be used completely offline if you download maps in advance - it doesn't take much device space for a really quite large area, and I traveled round northern Scotland that way last year with almost no signal but excellent navigation.

Answer (score 3):

Most bookshops sell paper maps - [Waterstones](https://www.waterstones.com/bookshops) is the big national chain, but local bookshops will sell them too.

You can also pick up 2-3 year old road atlases in many bargain bookshops (e.g. [The Works](https://www.theworks.co.uk/storelocator)) for about £2.  It's probably cheaper than buying them online, given you'd have to pay postage too.

If you head to the local tourist information centre, they often have free maps within leaflets for either specific attractions, or a group of local places.  Depending on what you're after, they may be sufficient in some cases.  They certainly would be as a supplement to a national road atlas.

Answer (score 3):

Just buy one of these,

https://www.amazon.co.uk/2018-Collins-Road-Atlas-Britain/dp/0008214557

[image]

I *think* those are still widely available in the UK.

- bookshops at the airport (when you arrive)?
- at petrol stations en route?
- certainly at large bookstores in cities.

I much prefer "real, old-fashioned" paper folding maps,

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Explorer-Purbeck-Dorchester-Weymouth-Swanage/dp/0319242544

[image]

but they're harder to find.

(Well, trivially available online - if you have time just buy one from amazon **.co.uk** and they'll post it to you in Oz.)

There's actually a famous **map shop** in London, if you're in London you should go .. stanfords.co.uk‎

Comment: The asker implies their father lives in the uk, so getting Amazon to deliver to him would be more sensible than sending the map to Australia.

Comment: @Fattie - was blissfully unaware of stanfords until you mentioned it. There's also one in Bristol according to their website ... will have to pay a visit (I'm down there in the summer)

Comment: re: Stanfords - visited the shop in Bristol.  I assume the London one's bigger, but ... wow.  I went downstairs and eavesdropped on a telephone conversation of a chap on the desk who was helping someone over the phone.  They were after walking map for some bizarre Eastern European country ... Azerbaijan maybe or Armenia - somewhere like that ... incredible customer service, he spent _so_ long on the phone going through everything, going _in detail_ through accuracy problems with one of the maps they wanted ... incredible.

Comment: right, a great british institution !

Answer (score 1):

An option no one else has mentioned is to pop into a local [Halfords](http://www.halfords.com), which is your one stop car/bike/cycle parts and motoring-related-tat superstore chain - the nearest one to Bridport is in Dorchester.

Answer (score 1):

As an ex-Brit I'd vote for buying a cheap road atlas from a service station (or Halfords) when you land.

But, another option if you're in the Perth Metro W.A. and desperate to plan ahead is to try here:-
http://www.chartandmapshop.com.au

It's a great shop to just browse in and should have what you're looking for.